# changing generated tomcat jsp files

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I'd like to do some testing on the jasper generated jsp files (not the original jsp from the webapp), so I edited the java files that are contained in tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/myWebApp and recompiled them on my own.

But every time when I restart tomcat, jasper recompiles the jsp from the webapp and thus overwrites my changes. I tried editing the generated files *after* the server has started, but tomcat still recompiles them from the originals. I suspect tomcat is somehow detecting if the original and generated files are in sync. Is there a way to disable that?

Comment: Editing the .java file won't change anything to the .class file anyway. What do you mean by "I'd like to do some testing"?

Comment: @JB I recompiled them on my own.

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen if you have not made changes to the JSP in webapps.
Normally jsps are monitored by tomcat for updates and recompiled only if the date on the 
jsp is after the date on it's compiled .class file. This will be an exception when HOT code replacement is configured for the server.

Comment: I am not sure if you are heading in the right direction. Directly doing changes in work directory and restarting server can have wierd results. You dont have to restart server when you are working in Work directory. HOT code replacement happens in Debug mode when using IDE. Is this something you are into?